# C++ Cython Map operations returns {b'a': 2} rather than {'a': 2}

Tags: python, c++, cython, stdmap

Why does the following code print {b'a': 2} rather than {'a': 2}. And how can I fix it:

File1: parameters.pyx

```
# parameters.pyx
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.string  cimport string

cdef class Parameters:
    cdef map[string,int] data
    cdef int myVal

    def __init__(self):
        self.data['a'] = 1
        self.myVal = 0

    cpdef void change_data(self, map[string,int] newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    cpdef map[string,int] print_data(self):
        print(self.data)

    cpdef void change_myVal(self):
        self.myVal = 3
```

File2

```
# model.pyx

#from parameters import Parameters
from parameters import Parameters
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.string  cimport string

cpdef single_run():
    parameters = Parameters()

    cdef map[string,int] newMap
    
    newMap['a'] = 2

    parameters.change_data(newMap)

    
    parameters.print_data()

    parameters.change_myVal()
```

Setup.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(["*.py","*.pyx"],
language="c++")
    
)
```

Comment: The code prints b'a': 2 because the keys in the map from libcpp.string are C++ strings, which are byte-like objects when converted to Python.

Comment: how can I fix this problem? How can I get it to append correctly, i.e. 'a':2

Comment: There are multiple ways, try to find it by yourself, now its time where U learn gg

Comment: Can you point to a couple of the ways?

Comment: `b'a'` is a byte string, what used to be the default string type in python. Now the default is unicode, displayed as just `'a'`.  Both are usable in python.  One just has the `b` marker.

Comment: @user58925 was your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use :

```
d = {b'a': 2}
```

as the `b'a'` is a byte object.

If you want to convert it into string you can use `decode("utf-8")` on byte object:

```
d = {k.decode("utf-8"):v for k,v in d.items()}

print(d)

#output
{'a': 2}
```